# Why my API-Plateform resource give me always and only 2 attributes in response?

Tags: php, symfony, nested, api-platform.com

I try to create a new API rest on monolithic project with symfony 4.4, api-platform 2.6.8, i have to use yaml configuration, but i have the same issue with annotation.
One of my resource send 2 attributes (ID and label) when i try GET request on collection, whatever the configuration.

The entity :

```
 /**
 * Structure.
 *
 * @Gedmo\Tree(type="nested")
 * @ORM\Table(name="por_structure")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Common\StructureBundle\Repository\StructureRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"parent", "code", "status"}, errorPath="code", message="common.structure.code.unique")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"parent", "label", "status"}, errorPath="label", message="common.structure.label.unique")
 */
class Structure
{
    /**
     * ID of the structure node.
     *
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * Label of the structure node.
     *
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\Column(name="label", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $label;

    /**
     * External ID of the structure node.
     *
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\Column(name="code", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $code;

    /**
     * Accounting code of the structure node.
     *
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="accounting_code", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $accountingCode;

    /**
     * Status of the node (1: enabled, 0:disabled).
     *
     * @var bool
     * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="boolean")
     */
    private $status;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeLeft
     * @ORM\Column(name="lft", type="integer")
     */
    private $lft;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeLevel
     * @ORM\Column(name="lvl", type="integer")
     */
    private $lvl;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeRight
     * @ORM\Column(name="rgt", type="integer")
     */
    private $rgt;

    /**
     * @var Structure
     * @Gedmo\TreeRoot
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Common\StructureBundle\Entity\Structure")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="root", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $root;
[...]
```

The resources.yaml :

```
resources:
  #Structure
  Common\StructureBundle\Entity\Structure:
    shortName: 'Common/Structure'
    properties:
      id:
        identifier: true
    collectionOperations:
      get:
        openapi_context:
          summary: 'Récupère une collection de Structure'
          description: 'Récupère une collection de Structure'
        normalization_context:
          groups: [ 'a2:read:Structure']
          openapi_definition_name: 'collection-read'
```

And the serializer.yaml (result is the same without any attribute in it):

```
Common\StructureBundle\Entity\Structure:
  attributes:
    id:
      groups: [ 'a2:read:Structure' ]
    label:
      groups: [ 'a2:read:Structure' ]
    code:
      groups: [ 'a2:read:Structure' ]
    status:
      groups: [ 'a2:read:Structure' ]
```

The GET answer is still :

```
{
  "@context": "\/api\/contexts\/Common\/Structure",
  "@id": "\/api\/v2\/common\/structures",
  "@type": "hydra:Collection",
  "hydra:member": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "label": "SOCIETE 1 (FR)"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "label": "Défaut"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "label": "ZForfait jours"
    },
    [...]
    ],
  "hydra:totalItems": 42
}
```

What did i do wrong ?

Comment: Did you try clearing the cache?

Comment: yes i clear the cache between any change, the response still the same :(

Answer (score 0):

OK i found the problem.

I work on a big application and somewhere i didn't know, there is a serialization process which used classes implementing NormalizerInterface.

in these classes there is the definition which locked the output.

I change NormalizerInterface, ContextAwareNormalizerInterface, and add something special in the context when thes are called by the other part of the app.